# python: print non inherited methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am trying to print a list of the methods that have not been inherited from other classes (e.g.., not inheritted from `object` or another base class). As an example say I have the following class:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.__x=x
        self.__y=y
```

calling this method should print: 
`[__init__]` without `__str__` (inheritted from object).

I've tried:

```
dir(Point)
```

but the problem is that it includes already inheritted methods.

Comment: As an aside, I would suggest *not* using double-underscore name-mangling unless you actually need it (to prevent name-clashes in subclasses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into the `__dict__` of the class itself:

```
import types

def list_methods(t):
    for name, item in t.__dict__.items():
        if isinstance(item, types.FunctionType):
            print(name)
```

`t` is a class object here, not an instance of a class. If you want to operate on instances, replace `t.__dict__.items()` with `type(t).__dict__.items()` in the loop.

Comment: Do I call it on an object of type Point or do I call it on the Point class itself?

Comment: On the class itself.

Comment: I tried it and an error is produced ie: `AttributeError: module 'types' has no attribute 'FunctiobType'`. Do I need to import some module?

Comment: What error was produced? And yes, you need `import types`

Comment: I also had a missing call to items. Fixed now.

Comment: So it is. Fixed

Comment: you can always do `FunctionType = type(lambda x:x)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. No need to make another object. `type(list_methods)` will work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

To print the non-inherited attributes of an object, such as a class object, use `vars` which checks the `__dict__` of that object:

```
In [1]: class Point:
   ...:     def __init__(self, x, y):
   ...:         self.__x=x
   ...:         self.__y=y
   ...:

In [2]: vars(Point)
Out[2]:
mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Point' objects>,
              '__doc__': None,
              '__init__': <function __main__.Point.__init__>,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Point' objects>})
```

Since a method is merely a callable object in the class, you can check for it using something to the effect of:

```
In [3]: for k, v in vars(Point).items():
   ...:     if callable(v):
   ...:         print(k)
   ...:
__init__
```